# PhP Else If not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to show a specific member level a specific menu.
If the Member is level 2 he gets the right menu.
But if he is level 3 the menu "nexusmitglied" doesn't show up.

What did I do wrong?

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    $member_level = SwpmMemberUtils::get_logged_in_members_level();
    if((SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in()) || ($member_level == "2")) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    } 
    $member_level = SwpmMemberUtils::get_logged_in_members_level();
    else if((SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in()) || ($member_level == "3")) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'nexusmitglied';
    } else 
    {
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    }
    return $args;
}  
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Comment: You redefined `$member_level` variable after closing curly brace `}` for `if statement` but before starting `else if statement` effectively causing an error in syntax.

Comment: That wasn't the problem, it worked with both

Comment: I did not offer a solution. I pointed at a mistake in your syntax which Joris Wagter corrected in his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the `||` (or) operator the first statement is always valid if a member is logged in. So the else if is never reached.

Use `&&` instead. You also only have to create `$member_level` once. Leave out the extra braces in the if statement because they are not needed and only clutter the code. Use single quotes for plain strings. Php expects variables between double quotes so single quotes are always parsed faster than double.

```
$member_level = SwpmMemberUtils::get_logged_in_members_level();

if(SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in() && $member_level == '2') { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else if(SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in() && $member_level == '3') { 
    $args['menu'] = 'nexusmitglied';
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped you. My pleasure!

Comment: Hello, I have a question, what should I write when I want the menu "nexusmitglied" shown for level 3,4 and 5. ?

Comment: Got it! Just add it with OR $member_level == '4'

Comment: You wil need to put it between braces so it still checks is a member is logged in.  Don't use the `OR` operator but use `||`. Like this: `else if(SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in() && ( $member_level == '3' || $meber_level == '4' || $member_level == '5') )` or you yould use `in_array` to make it shorter. `else if( SwpmMemberUtils::is_member_logged_in() && in_array($member_level, ['3', '4', '5']) )`